# How do you recreate a Datadog Synthetics Browser test in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, monitoring, datadog

I am attempting to build a series of synthetic browser tests in Datadog via Terraform using a map of URLs. The test will go to a URL, type dummy credentials into the login form, attempt to log in, and assert that there will be an invalid username/password response. My code fails when I attempt to run a `terraform apply`. I have referenced the documentation, but I have not been able to find examples of browser tests with step types of `typeText`. Have I set up my params incorrectly?

**Code:**

```
resource "datadog_synthetics_test" "login_tests" {
  for_each = var.browser_test_urls
  type = "browser"

  request_definition {
    method = "GET"
    url = each.value
  }

  device_ids = ["laptop_large"]
  locations = ["aws:us-east-1"]

  options_list {
    tick_every = 1800
    follow_redirects = true

    retry {
      count    = 2
      interval = 60000 
    }
  }

  name = "Login Test for ${each.key}"
  message = "Login test failed for ${each.key} on url ${each.value}"

  status = "paused"

  browser_step {
    name = "Type Username"
    type = "typeText"
    params {
      element = "#userItem"
      value = "username"
    }
  }

    browser_step {
    name = "Type Password"
    params {
      element = "#passItem"
      value = "password"
    }
    type = "typeText"
  }

    browser_step {
    name = "Click Login Button"
    params {
      element = "#btlogin"
    }
    type = "click"
  }

  browser_step {
    name = "Check for Invalid Login Message"
    params {
      check = "contains"
      value = "Invalid username or password!"
    }
    type = "assertPageContains"
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
│ Error: error creating synthetics browser test from https://us3.datadoghq.com/api/v1/synthetics/tests/browser: 400 Bad Request: {"errors":["Invalid steps data: 
Step 0 has invalid params: None is not of type 'object'"]}
│
│   with module.datadog.datadog_synthetics_test.login_tests["Test"],
│   on modules\datadog\browser_tests.tf line 1, in resource "datadog_synthetics_test" "login_tests":
│    1: resource "datadog_synthetics_test" "login_tests" {
```

Answer (score 3):

To anyone facing a similar issue, this is how I ended up solving it.

I created the synthetic through the Datadog UI, and then imported it into my terraform state. From there I looked at my state file to see the value of the element property. It was a long x-path style. I copied and pasted the entire string into my element property, and it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar setup but opted to use `element_user_locator` to avoid needing to store the large XPATH/JSON config object. However, I'm not sure if this eliminates the "self-healing" benefits of Synthetics testing.

Example:

```
browser_step {
  name = "Click login link"
  type = "click"
  params {
    element_user_locator {
      value {
        type  = "css"
        value = "a[href='/login']"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is a decoded version of the `browser_step.param.element` expected JSON object (I found it a bit too unwieldy to want to utilize):

```
{
  "multiLocator": {
    "ab": "/html[1]/body[1]/div[1]/div[1]/header[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/p[1]/a[1]",
    "at": "/descendant::*[@href='/login']",
    "cl": "/descendant::*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' jss31 ')]/descendant::*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' MuiTypography-body1 ')]/a[1]",
    "clt": "/descendant::*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' jss31 ')]/descendant::*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' MuiTypography-body1 ')]/descendant::*[text()[normalize-space(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞŸŽŠŒ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿžšœ')) = 'log into your account']]",
    "co": [
      {
        "text": "log into your account",
        "textType": "directText"
      }
    ],
    "ro": "//*[text()[normalize-space(translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞŸŽŠŒ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþÿžšœ')) = 'log into your account']]"
  },
  "targetOuterHTML": "<a href='/login'>Log into your account</a>",
  "url": "https://www.example.com/"
}
```